# DateTime stored in SQL Server DB does not account for daylight savings time. How can I fix this when I pull it out?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, dst

A machine that I do not have control of logs datetimes in EST. It doesn't switch for daylight savings time. When I pull data out it screws up all my reports by an hour. Is there a way to fix this in my query? Using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: The problem is when the "wrong" time has been stored, you can no longer determine if a row you're reading is from before or after the time change. You can fix things when the clock skips an hour (DST begins, one hour is "lost") but not when it goes back an hour (DST ends, one hour "happens twice"). You may be able to fix things if there's another column that's monotonically increasing (or nearly so) like an ID, but even so the query for that won't be fun.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your query by using CASE:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
     CASE WHEN (date_col BETWEEN ... AND ...)
            OR (date_col BETWEEN ... AND ...)
            OR (date_col BETWEEN ... AND ...)
          THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 1, date_col) ELSE date_col END AS date_col
FROM tab_name;
```

I would also update existing values and fix saving from application to avoid this kind of scenario in the future.

Comment: The issue is that DST doesn't fall on the same date every year : /

Comment: @user1904766 And where is the problem to add more conditions for example for few years behind and/or ahead?